# What is the possible number of states in the DFA of intersection of two given FA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> Consider a DFA over $a,b$  accepting all strings having number of $a$ 's divible by 6 and number of $b$ 's divisble by 8. What is the minimum number of states in the resultant DFA ?

This problem can be solved by assuming 2 DFAs. One accepting the number of $a$ 's divible by 6 and the other accepting with number of $b$ 's divisble by 8. And then taking intersection of them. So what will be the number of states in the resultant DFA?

I tried drawing the DFA accepting all strings having number of $a$ 's divible by 3 and number of $b$ 's divisble by 3, and found it to have 3x3 (9) states. Can I asssume the reuslt to be 48 states for this case? Can it be inferred that the for string accepting number of $a$ 's divible by $m$  and number of $b$ 's divisble by $n$ , there will be $mn$  states? Or I need to draw it by hand? Or anything other? Any subtle hint will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product construction shows that if $L_1$ is accepted by a DFA having $n_1$ states and $L_2$ is accepted by a DFA having $n_2$ states then $L_1 \cap L_2$ is accepted by a DFA having $n_1n_2$ states; browse back to the product construction to understand why. The resulting DFA need not be minimal even if the DFAs for $L_1$ and $L_2$ were (a trivial example is given by $L_1 = L_2$, assuming $n_1>1$). In your case, this means that if you can find a DFA for $\{w : 6\mid \#_a(w)\}$ having six states and one for $\{w : 8\mid \#_b(w)\}$ having eight states, then you can find a DFA for the intersection having 48 states.

Is this DFA minimal? You can use the Myhill–Nerode criterion to show that indeed it is: the 48 words $\{ a^i b^j : 0 \leq i < 6, \; 0 \leq j < 8 \}$ are pairwise incomparable.

Comment: Great !!
So, can I positively assume that for FA accepting strings having a's divisible by m, and b's divisible by n, there ought to be mxn states in the minimal FA?

Comment: You don't have to assume anything. You can *prove* that it exists. If you're still unsure, you can try to construct the DFA directly (by following the product construction).

Comment: Okay. I was just trying to memorize a few direct results so that they can help me in my exams. Thanks! :)